# CSV file export with encoding issues

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to export a SQL Server table into a CSV file:

Data in the table is like = Presentación or Difusión

All is working good... but in the `.CSV` file I find:

```
Presentaci&#243;n or Difusi&#243;n
```

This is my .cs code:

```
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.DataBind();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
{
    // add separator
    sb.Append(GridView1.Columns[k].HeaderText + ';');
}

// append new line
sb.Append("\r\n");

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        // add separator
        sb.Append(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text + ';');
    }

    // append new line
    sb.Append("\r\n");
}

Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=OrigenDatos.csv");  
Response.Charset = encoding.EncodingName;
Response.ContentType = "application/text";
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Is UTF-8 the true charset?

Comment: utf's a charset, but your text is undoubtedly utf with html encoding.

Comment: utf-8 is especified on my webform.aspx @MarcB                                                         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

Comment: Have a look at my answer. More information you can find here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.2.2

Answer (score 2):

In order to correctly decode an HTML file, your browser needs to know which encoding to use. You can tell it to him by setting the [charset parameter](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index) or by setting [meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp): `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

So: you need to save the HTML file using UTF-8 and declare that encoding properly.

It can also theoretically be that on your server default encoding is other as UTF-8 - then you should delete the `AddDefaultCharset your_encoding` from the .htaccess server file and write `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`. But I am not sure that this is about your case.

**EDIT:**

The byte `&#243;` stands for Spanish character ó in UTF-8. So I think you should not try to encode with other encodings, because it is definitely utf-8.

Comment: CMS wiht C#/ASP.NETdoes not support .htaccess configurations

Comment: Ok, it is good to know. If your issue is not solved, I will have an update for you whta you can try else

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this below code

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName, Encoding.UTF8) + "");
        Response.Cookies.Add(new System.Web.HttpCookie("fileDownload", "true"));
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
        Response.Write(outPutStringData); // Information which you want in .csv file
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```